# Cannot create registry key value with WiX installer

Tags: wix, installation

The below component does everything as expected, but fails to write the last registry key value. I get no errors.

```
<Component Id="ProgramMenuDir" Guid="68977683-3F36-45EF-9FF4-7B9461A42D06">
<RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuDir" On="uninstall" />
<RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Wow6432Node\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes">
    <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="APIUrl" Value="http://api.blah/" KeyPath="yes" />
    <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Token" Value="blah" />
</RegistryKey>
<RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Wow6432Node\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\Tokens" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes" />
<RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Wow6432Node\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\Tokens\WOvN+Lac+d3wRtY0uBUsAeHTYg4x7j2/NWpftWv/16qaOz3J6TpDQmvjUpQmoCWPSFdMpbrcpi4rJd56aBKkkvSR54RsS5xueaYfPgk1QmQ=" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes" />
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Action="write" Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" Name="[ProductName]" Value="blah" Type="string" />
</Component>
```

Why no write, yet no errors?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you just looking in the wrong place, if this is a 32 bit installer then you need to check the following location - **HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft**

Remember that these are the equivalent nodes depending on your install architecture:

**32bit installer on 64bit machine:**

```
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft
```

**32bit installer on 32bit machine or 64bit installer on 64bit machine:**

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft
```

Comment: Thank you David. I was aware that there was a difference, but didn't know where to look. It was right under my nose. Thanks again.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but the registry keys are not under Wow6432 either. Can you help ?